# SSIS package Job Fails with Unexpected Termination

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I scheduled a SSIS package in SQL Server 2012 Agent which fails sometime with "Unexpected Termination" without any error message.

Any Idea why it happens?

Comment: No idea at all. There is an error message you just have to go look for it in the various logs availble to you in SQL Server, Windows, or your SSIS package.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs with SQL Server 2012 SP1.

I went through these KB articles

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2837964
and
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2993859

and installed the suggested hot-fixes that resolved the error.